# Styling the hint on a HTML5 input field using required attribute

Tags: css, forms, html, input, required

Is it possible to style the hint that appears on a HTML5 input field when using the required attribute. If you're not sure what I'm talking about click submit on this form without filling anything in. You should have a hint popup.

http://24ways.org/examples/have-a-field-day-with-html5-forms/24ways-form.html

I've checked the CSS source and couldn't see anything regarding the hint.

I have found that styling the div element in a reset fashion affects how it appears. But I do not know how to target it specifically.

Please note: I am NOT referring to a placeholder.

Cheers,
Thomas.

Comment: I just checked it in FF4 and the hint actually is positioned static: it doesn't follow the input, just stays on screen no matter where you scroll - not very good! It's actually freaking out and going everywhere when I scroll!

Comment: Doesn't show up at all in FF3.6. Seems to work fine in Chrome.

Comment: Besides semantics, one of the main reasons for using the "required" attribute is to let the browser handle it. If you want to use your own code for validation then don't use it. If accessibility is your main concern use "aria-required=true"

Answer (score 13):

The reason, why you can style the error bubble with a div-selector is a bug in Chrome 11/12, which should be [fixed in newer version](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=75766)s. There are some pseudoclasses to style the error bubble in Chrome 12 (and maybee in Safari6) (::-webkit-validation-bubble etc.). You can find the full HTML structure including the pseudoelement selectors and some styling examples in the [following document](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#WebKitr82180orlater).

Note, that this is a webkit extension to the HTML5 form constraint validation and non-standard. If you want to use a way to style the error message in all HTML5 validation supporting browsers, you have to use JavaScript.

The key principle of this, is that you have to add a handler to the invalid-event (Note: The invalid event does not bubble) and then prevent the default interaction. This will remove the browsers native error bubble and you are able to implement a custom styleable UI in all HTML5 browsers.

```
//Note: that we use true for useCapture, because invalid does not bubble
document.addEventListener('invalid', function(e){
    //prevent the browser from showing his error bubble
    e.preventDefault();
    //now you can implement your own validation UI (showError is a Custom method which has to be implemented by you
    showError(e.target, $.prop(e.target, 'validationMessage');
}, true);
```

The code above will call showError for all invalid elements in the current form. If you want to do this only for the first invalid element you can do the following:

```
document.addEventListener('invalid', (function(){
    var isFirst = true;
    return function(e){
        //prevent the browser from showing his error bubble
        e.preventDefault();
        //now you can implement your own validation UI
        if(isFirst){
            showError(e.target, $.prop(e.target, 'validationMessage');
            //set isFirst to false
            isFirst = false;
            //reset isFirst to true, so user can try to submit invalid forms multiple times
            setTimeout(function(){
                isFirst = true;
            }, 9);
        }
    };
})(), true);
```

In case you are using jQuery for your site, I would recommend using [webshims lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html). webshims lib implements the HTML5 constraint validation in all browsers (including IE6) and gives a simple extension for generating a simple custom styleable validation message. The JS code looks like this:

```
$(document).bind('firstinvalid', function(e){
    $.webshims.validityAlert.showFor( e.target ); 
    //prevent browser from showing native validation message 
    return false; 
});
```

The HTML-structure generated by `$.webshims.validityAlert.showFor` looks like this:

```
<span class="validity-alert" role="alert"> 
    <span class="va-arrow"><span class="va-arrow-box"></span></span> 
    <span class="va-box">Error message of the current field</span> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can style the validation bubble in webkit using the following pseudo-selectors:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-outer-arrow
::-webkit-validation-bubble-top-inner-arrow
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message
```

For Mozilla browsers there isn't a way yet. Mozilla does support `x-moz-errormessage` if you want to change the text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/input#section_5

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to disable the hints from showing.

Basically I found they're within a div element, in my reset if I add this to the top.

```
div { display: none; }
body div { display: block; }
```

Then the hints no longer appear, yet the rest of my divs work fine.

I'm also led to believe that the hints appear outside of the HTML document tag. As styling with html div also has no effect on the hints. Interesting stuff.

This only works in Chrome though.

Comment: That is very interesting, seems like they haven't figured this one out yet.

Comment: Interesting...probably not future proof.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the hints that say Opera and Chrome use then I'm afraid you can't.

Comment: There must be... because the ones that appear on the site above are way different to the ones that appear on my website. On my site they appear in a rounded corner transparent box.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup and http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html for further details.

Comment: Looks like [you can style them in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660177/styling-the-hint-on-a-html5-input-field-using-required-attribute/5660484#5660484), which is strange.

Comment: I'd hardly call that styling :-)

Comment: The reason you can style it in Chrome is because chrome uses JavaScript to put it on the page... it's actually a <div> element that is outside of the <html> tags. I found this when I was testing my CSS reset rules. You can't really do much too it though, not enough class hooks.

Comment: simmon is right, that's like trying to style the alert dialog, which is different in each browser.