# How to customize the notifcation message on HTML input tag with required flag

Tags: html, input, notifications, customization, required

In the HTML input tag, if the `required` attribute is set to true, the browser shows a notification to fill up the text box. This notification has different style in different browsers. So is there a way to customize the notification style so that it looks same in all browsers?

> > > > [tryit](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required) in different browsers.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Required input styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249152/html5-required-input-styling)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do so by using JavaScript to override the behaviour but the most likely result is that people would stop using your site as they are used to the behaviour of the browser that they use all the time and be disconcerted to see something else.

Answer (score 1):

The `required` attribute is a feature of HTML5. You may know that HTML5 is not supported by all the browsers (e.g IE7,IE8). So you need to look for alternative JS solution for this.