# What are the input required attribute default declaration?

Tags: html, css

I am facing with a strange problem.

I have a `Wordpress` site, with `Mailchimp For Wordpress plugin`. There is the `email` field, what has a `required` attribute. Around the field, there are a red border or something.

First i inspected this element, turn of all the css properties, border still there.

I was really wondering why. Then when I removed the `required` attribute, the border has gone. So i thought I am on the right way, and add this to my css:

```
:required {
   border: none; outline: none;
}
```

That does not helped me out.

I visit this page: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_required.asp

But i do not see, what are the default declarations for this selector.

I also tried to search for required on w3.org wiki, no success.

So, of course my first question is how to remove that border, and the second is, where can I find the default declarations for required?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Required input styling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249152/html5-required-input-styling)

Comment: Also: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/invalid/

Comment: Thank you rnevius, I've added the `:invalid` selector, and `border: none;` what helps me.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[required], input:required {
    display:block; 
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you, i've did it, just has no effect. this is, becuase my field has `type="email"` and because of this, i've has to set the `:invalid` selector also. that was the solution.