# Replace html5 bubble messages with message under fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have the below code and I would like instead of bubbles  showing messages underneath the error fields. What addition should I make to my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#emailform').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            backedn validation

          }
        });

    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <form id="emailform" class="laform" method="post" action="*.php">


    <label>Email*: </label>

    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="input" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('The email address you entered is not valid')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}">

    <label class="col-md-12 labelcom">MSG</label>


    <textarea class="input2" name="comment" id="comment" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('This field is mandatory')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" placeholder="Enter your comments / suggestions..."></textarea>

    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="submit">SUBMIT</button>


  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the HTML `required` message is not possible. [More Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249152/html5-required-input-styling).

Just use Javascript and create your own validation checking and append messages under the elements if the validation fails.

---

**Edit**: After doing more research I found another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478800/override-css-for-html5-form-validation-required-popup) that contained more insightful information.

Apparently, it is possible. But you will have to use Javascript.

This code changes the message of the validation box the HTML `required` provides. You should probably look up browser support.

```
document.getElementById("input").setCustomValidity("Message");
```